# Не удаётся установить пакет с помощью 'pip install'

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, pip

При вводе в командную строку pip install channels выдаётся следующая ошибка:

```
Command "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ukqj6rx7\\twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-p4nvwv0y\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ukqj6rx7\twisted\
```

Если же устанавливать через виртуальную среду, то получаю следующее:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Тут конечно же всё предельно понятно, но обязательно ли устаналивать всю visual studio? Просто не планирую в ней работать, не хотелось бы загружать систему.
P.s. даже после установки 19й версии community ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Может, вам лучше PyCharm воспользоваться?

Comment: Проблема решилась путём установки visual build tools с оф. сайта. Надо пролистать ниже предлагаемой установки VS и выбрать в разделе инструменты нужный пакет.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хочется компилировать C extensions, а мейнтейнер пакета не предлагает прекомпилированный для нужной платформы, рекомендую заглядывать [сюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Christoph Gohlke поддерживает кучу пакетов для разных версий питона; зачастую проще найти и скачать нужный wheel, чем настроить среду для компиляции с какими-нибудь экзотическими зависимостями.

К примеру, [подборка для пакета `twisted`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted). Нужный пакет - `Twisted‑19.2.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`; когда скачается, выполни команду из терминала:

```
/> pip install C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\Twisted‑19.2.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```